# Can't send mail with Thunderbird 78.0b4

Tags: email, thunderbird

Anyone know how to remove the keys that Thunderbird 78.0b4 imported from my GPG keychain? I updated to the latest version of Tbird this morning and something got messed up. I get the below dialog box every time I try to send an email now. I've been all over the account settings, preferences and certs trying to find out where this key is at.

[image]

Comment: If you have in Thunderbird the Enigmail add-on (or pgp) then disable it. If on the Thunderbird menu you have OpenPGP then revoke the key using Key Management.

Comment: I've disabled Enigmail and under the Tools > OpenPGP Key Managment menu the '63...' key was there but I deleted it already. I also have the encryption and signing options de-selected under the Options menu in composer. Hoping I don't have to nuke my profile to solve this, but that's what it's looking like. I've got four different email accounts configured along with 4 calendars ugh...

Comment: Usually one cannot delete a key, only revoke it.

Comment: Dunno. Tools > OpenPGP key management and right click. "Delete" is there. I've nuked them all and the problem is still there. Going to try and restore from last night's backup.

Comment: Reverted to backup and things are back to normal now. Not going to do the "Goodbye Enigmail" migration for now anyway.